# randomization/permutation test for mean > 0

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, permutation-test

I'd like to know if the following procedure is a valid way to test if the mean of a population is greater than zero, based on a random sample of observations:

1) Calculate the sample mean

2) On each iteration of a large number of iterations, randomly flip or maintain the sign of each observation and recompute the mean.

3) Calculate the proportion of the means computed on the randomized data that are greater than or equal to the sample mean.

As I understand it, this procedure is valid if the observations reflect differences between paired samples.

I'm specifically interested in knowing if this procedure is still valid if the observations do **not** reflect the difference between paired samples.

Comment: if you want to test if the sample mean is greater than 0, why wouldn't you just stop at step 1 and compare it to 0?

Comment: You haven't fully described a test yet: what exactly would you do with that proportion of means greater than the sample mean?

Comment: Flipping signs in your permute step would correspond to an assumption (under the null) that the distribution was symmetric. This often makes sense when comparing paired data (e.g. consider measurements performed before and after some intervention and the assumption under the null that the treatment does nothing at all; flipping signs is simply interchanging before/after labels, which makes sense if the treatment has no impact on the distribution of the value within pairs).  For one-sample, it might sometimes make sense to assume symmetry under H0 but might otherwise be a surprising assumption

Answer (score 0):

Restating Glen_b's comment as an answer: the procedure is valid if you can assume that the distribution (under the null) is symmetric.